# Spacing a CSS animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm no expert at CSS and I've got a problem. On my [website](http://prohackr112.tk), I've got an animation in which images circle around an animation. These are not linked at all.

CSS:

```
#center {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.rotate {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 160px;
}

// ... code for animations
```

HTML (simplified):

```
<div id="center">
    <div class="view">
          <div class="plane main">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <img class="rotate" src="favicon.png width="64" height="64">
    <img class="rotate" src="favicon.png width="64" height="64">
    <img class="rotate" src="favicon.png width="64" height="64">
    <img class="rotate" src="favicon.png width="64" height="64">
    <img class="rotate" src="favicon.png width="64" height="64">
    <img class="rotate" src="favicon.png width="64" height="64">
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is make the `rotate` images circulate *around* the inner animation, instead of their positioning making it *seem* like they are. How could I do this without completely changing my code? As I said, I don't know much about CSS so none of the tutorials I viewed really tell me how I could do this easily. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The current animations are long and messy so I didn't include them here, but they're on a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pxs5hc5/1).

Comment: From the question , you want to implement rotate images without using positioning ...right?

Comment: you left out the most important part, the part you've already tried, the part for your current animations.

Comment: @NagaSaiA I do want them positioned... around the center animation.

Comment: @ryan If those are essential I'll add them.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.

Remove the second rotate from all the animations.
Then the images will always face the center. [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Do:

```
@keyframes rotate-1 {
    from { transform: rotate(-30deg) translateY(-200px)}
    to { transform: rotate(330deg) translateY(-200px)}
}
```

Instead of:

```
@keyframes rotate-1 {
    from { transform: rotate(-30deg) translateY(-200px) rotate(30deg) }
    to { transform: rotate(330deg) translateY(-200px) rotate(-330deg) }
}
```